# port 9 will not be opened on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wake-on-lan

i am tyring to wake on lan via my windows mobile phone so i can remote, i have port forwarded my 3389 port on my router correctly and allowed access via public in the firewall and it works however when i port forward port 9 for WOL and check via portchecktool.com the port remains blocked, i have created a rule in windows firewall called wol and allowed port 9 access but alas its still blocked port 3389 is open on the same site and works but port 9 is not.
is there any solution for me to be able to wake on lan over the internet and allow port 9 to be unblocked?

Comment: Did you first verify WOL works in the LAN? For security reasons (especially because there are no more free updates for Windows 7) you should not open the RDP port to the internet. I haven't tried myself, but the [TeamViewer forum](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/General-Questions/Setting-up-Wake-on-LAN-via-Public-Address/td-p/2138#) says you need to forward to the broadcast address. With Teamviewer as alternative to RDP, you could even configure it to wake and connect in one step.

Comment: Ports under 1024 are usually system-reserved. Do you absolutely need this one for WOL? As Furty mentioned, if WOL isn't available on your plaftform, you'll be hard pressed to enable it anyway.